How to see app engine resource allocation
I'm deploying an app to google app engine (flexible environment). My app.yaml file doesn't specify cpu, memory, or disk space currently. I assume it's using some default.
I want to know what the default settings are, but I can't find this information anywhere. Claude says I should be able to use gcloud app instances describe INSTANCE --service=SERVICE, -s SERVICE --version=VERSION, but it doesn't display the resource allocation. Here's what it gives me:

name: apps//services/default/versions/20241227t171225/instances/aef-default-20241227t171225-xc35
startTime: '2024-12-27T17:18:59.958Z'
vmIp: 34.173.160.11
vmLiveness: HEALTHY
vmStatus: RUNNING
vmZoneName: us-central1-b

Claude and Gemini both say I should be able to see the information in the GUI, but I don't see it there either. All I see is memory usage:

Any idea how I can get the resource allocation for a running instance?

Default settings are documented here (Resource Settings section of the app.yaml documentation).
Note: I linked to Python. You can switch the tab to the the programming language that you've used

Interesting. The reason I asked is because I was deploying yesterday and the app took 6-8 tries to launch. After setting the memory to 2gb, it launched fine so I assumed the default memory allotment was lower. But this article says it's 2.3gb.

@toppsdown - 2.3GB in the article I linked to was an example. The article says the default value for memory is 0.6GB

Got it, thanks for the clarification.
